# image resizing in azure not working when deployed locally

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-storage, imageresizer

```
<resizer>
    <plugins>
      <add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
      <add name="AzureReader2" connectionString="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" endpoint="http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/" />         
    </plugins>
  </resizer>
```

I am trying to implement image resizing in my **Mvc4** application using **"AzureReader2"**. I had installed all the nuget packages and modified **webconfig** file as above. It works fine when i tried to deploy on server. But locally it fails, it's says **"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."**.

Do any one faced the same issue, if so let me know the work around please.

Answer (score 1):

The local storage emulator for Azure hasn't been updated. Microsoft is working on fixing this. This isn't related to ImageResizer.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/11/27/windows-azure-storage-release-introducing-cors-json-minute-metrics-and-more.aspx

"As mentioned above an updated Windows Azure Storage Emulator is expected to ship with full support of these new features in the next couple of months. Users attempting to develop against the current version of the Storage emulator will receive Bad Request errors as the protocol version (2013-08-15) is unsupported. Until then, users wanting to use the new features would need to develop and test against a Windows Azure Storage Account to leverage the 2013-08-15 REST version."